# Efficient data structure for comparing changes

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, data-structures

I have a table of data on a sheet (`listObject`). I would like to write it to a vba data structure where I filter the columns, and compare the changes so that I can update the `listObject`

Currently my approach is to store the `listObject` as a `Collection` of `Arrays` where each array has a Key representing the column header. I then filter the arrays with [`Filter`](http://www.excelfunctions.net/vba-filter-function.html)

Now I have 2 issues;

1. I don't know which rows were filtered out for a given column [1D changes]

   - The inefficient solution is of course to loop over the values in original column and check against the filtered array, noting the row numbers where items are now missing
2. If more than one column is filtered I don't know which rows remain completely untouched [2D changes]

   - Here I'm referring to those times when a the rows filtered from each column don't match up - like filtering two columns of a table in a spreadsheet
   - One solution for this is just to repeat *1.* over each column, which isn't so inefficient

Is there a good vba data-structure which allows changes in either 1D arrays, or 2D arrays/collections of arrays/tables to be tracked?

Comment: Could you add what you currently have? So you have a table that gets filtered by the user and you want to check which rows are removed?

Comment: @UGP I was only suggesting quasi-code. i.e. This is the approach I would take - using a collection of arrays to model the `listObject` within VBA data structures. In terms of _how_ to check which rows were filtered, my current approach is to `Filter` then compare changes with a Loop, but I'm wondering if there's a datastructure that either allows me to compare changes between two arrays, or logs what gets filtered. N.B the user isn't filtering the `ListObject`; my internal data structure is populated by the `ListObject`,is filtered, then writes changes back by deleting rows of the `listObject`